# Web Scraping - Google reCAPTCHA

Tags: web-scraping, automation, google-api

I am working on an app, which will create an account on a gym website, then update personal data (I need to update some data like phone number, address etc, stuff I don't do at account creation step) and then use a promo code, use the free one time entry, and return the code (for that free entry) to me. I managed to automate creating an account, the problem with updating the personal data, is that the website in addition to using its own API and API tokens, also uses google's invisible reCAPTCHA. Before saving the newly added personal data, the website makes a request to this site: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=6LeWvggoAAAAANrb-a2ioXSYUzz2hbThramDh4LB which returns the `captchaToken` that I need.

I have observed that the URL doesn't change, but the payload it posts does change. It is the first time that I have seen this invisible captcha from google, and am very stuck. Is it even possible to automate that process? If so, I would greatly appreaciate any tips on what to look for while analyzing web traffic etc.